# Tensorflow: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker

Tags: tensorflow, containers, distribute

When I run on k8s, and my tensorflow code is in the docker container, this log is always showing for some worker:

> Distrubuted TensorFlow:
>   CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0

I don't know why. The network in the cluster is ok, how to solve it?

Comment: details:    and some workers can training normally ,but some workers will  always print that log, the network is ok both in docker and host. so how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pull the docker image on k8s nodes first?

So that pulling image will not disturb TF execute order.